# Controller disposal in IHttpControllerActivator

Tags: c#, simple-injector

I have a custom `IHttpControllerActivator` for my web api controllers which I'm using along with simple injector:

```
public sealed class ApiControllerActivator : IHttpControllerActivator
{
    private readonly Container _container;
    private readonly IHttpControllerActivator _original;

    public ApiControllerActivator(Container container, IHttpControllerActivator original)
    {
        _container = container;
        _original = original;
    }

    public IHttpController Create(HttpRequestMessage request,
                        HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
    {
        var controller = CreateController(request, controllerDescriptor, controllerType);
        // request.RegisterForDispose(...); required?
        return controller;
    }

    private IHttpController CreateController(HttpRequestMessage request, 
                        HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
    {
        if (controllerType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(WebApiController)))
        {
            return (IHttpController) _container.GetInstance(controllerType);
        }

        return _original.Create(request, controllerDescriptor, controllerType);
    }
}
```

Registration:

`GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerActivator), new ApiControllerActivator(container, GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.GetHttpControllerActivator()));`

Do I need to handle any disposal of the controller, or is it handled by the framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to handle any disposal of the controller

The short answer is: as long as you register your Web API controllers using the `RegisterWebApiControllers()` extension method, you do not need to handle the disposal of your controllers.

The long answer is that when you call `RegisterWebApiControllers`, Simple Injector will actually *not* dispose your controllers at all, but you will get a `VerificationException` when you override `Dispose(bool)` in one of your controllers when you call `Container.Verify()`.

The reasoning is as follows: Simple Injector will only dispose of disposable classes when they are registered as either `Scoped` or `Singleton`. `Transient` registrations are never disposed. The `RegisterWebApiControllers` extension method, however, registers controllers as `Transient`.

When registering a disposable `Transient` in Simple Injector, it would typically cause a `DisposableTransientComponent` warning, when `Verify` is called. Since, however, the `ApiController` base class does implement `IDisposable`, but its `Dispose(bool)` method is a no-op, not disposing it is not be a problem, unless the derived controller explicitly overrides `Dispose(bool)`.

Because of that, `RegisterWebApiControllers` simply suppresses this warning when it makes the registration. When it finds that the derived controller class *does* override `Dispose(bool)`, however, it will discard the suppression and you will see `Verify()` warn you about this disposable type, because not disposing such type would be a problem.

The idea behind this behavior is that the need to actually implement disposable logic on a controller would be really rare, because a controller itself would typically not have to deal with unmanaged resources. This is typically something that lower level components will do, but, when registered correctly, those components will be disposed by Simple Injector. If you have a controller that has dispose logic, you should consider refactoring it and moving that resource out of the controller, into a different component.

In the extremely rare case that having dispose logic on a controller itself makes the most sense, you will either have to:

- Register that particular controller as `Scoped`
- Or suppress the warning on that controller and register that controller for disposal in the request's active `Scope` using `container.RegisterInitializer<MyControllerType>(c => Lifestyle.Scope.RegisterForDisposal(container, c));`

Comment: I see. Thank you for the detailed explanation (as usual). I've decompiled the Umbraco source and they are not overriding `Dispose(bool)`, so I guess I'm safe sticking to my current implementation using `container.Register(controllerType, controllerType, Lifestyle.Transient);` along with my own supression (I only want to register a subset of web api controllers).

Comment: Please use the `RegisterMvcControllers` and `RegisterWebApiControllers` extension methods in combination with `Container.Verify()`. If you do so, Simple Injector will notify you if anything is overriding `Dispose(bool)`. No need to look at the Umbraco source code, and no need to register your controllers manually.

Comment: If I do that and set the depenency resolvers according to the manual, simple injector will interfere with Umbraco's backoffice controllers. I only want to use simple injector for my own controllers. With that being said, I suppose explicitly registering my own controllers and use a custom controller activator for wep api along with a custom controller factory for MVC is the way to go?